# Manually changing symmetry

Tags: symmetry

I have two crystal structures, one in R3m and one in Cm symmetry. Both structures also differ in stoichiometric ratios, $ABC_4$ and $A_2B_2C_8$, respectively. Both structures look nigh on identical, with the exception of double the amount of atoms in one than the other.

How would I go about manually changing the symmetry of the Cm structure to R3m symmetry? I normally use VESTA as a visualization tool, and Avogadro as a tool for imposing symmetry.

Comment: Never heard of a group R3m

Comment: @Maurice space group 160: http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/large/160az1.htm

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hard to answer because it lacks a lot of information.  $Cm$ (IT #8) belongs to the monoclinic which does not say anything about the threefold symmetry axes present in $R3m$ (IT #160).  But it is not unheard to transfer a monoclinic  model into one that belongs to the  trigonal / rhombohedral system.

Sadly, however, your question does not include a hint about the data and programs other than VESTA (for which I lack working knowledge) with you, nor your previous exposure to crystallography.  Of course the best were to start all over with reducing the diffraction data to write a new .hkl file, now with the hypothesis of higher symmetry present, to solve and refine the model again.  However, if you have a) a modern .cif file (those now including the hkl data and even better a good portion of the ShelX .res file), or b) one of the older .cif file *plus* the structure factors than you could give Platon's `addsym`instruction a try. This routine was just written for the purpose of identifying missed symmetries.  It will write you a new .hkl, for lattice constants already adjusted, and an .ins file (with Laue symmetry updated accordingly) to start over with ShelX or Olex2.

By today's standards, [Platon](https://www.platonsoft.nl/platon/pl000000.html) neither truly is CLI, nor GUI (mainly a large FORTRAN 77 executable + X-window; executables available Linux, Mac and Windows), but well documented in publications by Spek himself including many worked test data.  For `addsym` the page in question is [here](https://www.platonsoft.nl/platon/pl000401.html).  Don't forget to check the model if it still is chemically sensible (bond lengths / angles, ADP ellipsoids, void volumes) and *significantly* better, e.g. by [Hamilton's R-factor ratio test](https://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?a04554).